# Kibana not showing large text

Tags: kibana, elk

I have a csv that has a very large value in URL (some gibrish values). The text exceeds even 30 lines in an editor.
Kibana shows only a portion of that text (probably due to some display settings), even if I select the correct column. The text in elastic is much more larger than coming up in the column in picture
[image]

When I keep expanding further after expanding a selected row, I can see the full data.
[image] Now I cannot keep doing that for every logline. I need kibana to show full data in each row.
I read somewhere that there is a setting for this in Kibana, but I couldn't locate that in this version of kibana.
The source CSV file is here- https://s3.amazonaws.com/botsdataset/botsv1/json-by-sourcetype/botsv1.stream-http.json.gz

Answer (score 3):

Ok , so for the reference of others who might struggle with this,
Goto -
**Advanced settings of kibana (through search box) => Maximum table cell height** 
Change the value to **zero** to disable it and kibana won't truncate any text.